# How do I pre-populate an Angular 7 menu used as an attribute of adding a component?

Tags: angular, drop-down-menu, components, angular7

I'm using Angular 7.  I define an order, src/app/order.ts, like this

```
import { Product } from './product';

export class Order{
    public id:number;
    public reference:string;
    public product:Product;

}
```

I created an add order component, src/app/order-add/order-add.component.html, that looks like this

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-xs-4 control-label" for="orderProduct">Product: </label>
        <div class="col-xs-8">
              <select [(ngModel)]="order.product" name="orderProduct">
                <option *ngFor="let product of products; let i = index" [value]="products[i].id" [selected]="order !== 'undefined' && products[i].id == order.product.id">
                  {{products[i].name}}
                </option>
              </select>
        </div>

        <label class="col-xs-4 control-label" for="orderReference">Order Reference: </label>
        <div class="col-xs-8">
            <input type="text" style="width: 300px" class="form-control" required
                [(ngModel)]="order.reference" name="orderReference">
        </div>
        <div>
                <input type="submit" [value]="order.id !== undefined ? 'Update' : 'Create'" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Below is how I define what gets loaded in src/app/order-add/order-add.component.ts ...

```
...
export class OrderAddComponent implements OnInit {

  public order : Order = new Order();
  public products : Array<Product>;

  constructor(public apiService: ApiService , public acRoute : ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    // Get current products list for display on order form
    this.apiService.get("products").subscribe((data : Product[])=>{
      console.log(data);
      this.products = data;
    });

    // Get info about order
    this.acRoute.params.subscribe((data : any)=>{
      console.log(data.id);
      if(data && data.id){
        this.apiService.get("orders/"+data.id).subscribe((data : Order)=>{
          this.order = data;
        });
      }
      else
      {
        this.order = new Order();
      }
    })
  }
```

The issue is that when my page initially loads, there are no products in my drop-down until I actually click on the select menu and attempt to load something.  There is this error in the JS console that appears before anything is done ...

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (OrderAddComponent.html:6)
    at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (core.js:14735)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13849)
    at callViewAction (core.js:14195)
    at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:14153)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13845)
    at callViewAction (core.js:14195)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:14127)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13850)
    at callViewAction (core.js:14195)
```

How can I make sure my menu is pre-populated without my having to click on the SELECT menu?

Comment: Why target a specific index of products instead of just using product that comes from the ngFor? As in product.id and product.name

Comment: I'm open to that, but isn't that what I'm doing with my ' [(ngModel)]="order.product"' section?

Comment: Sure you are doing that with order, but you are not doing that with products and that ngFor. Also at the base level could be the issue of order and products coming in at different times, you could consider using ngIf to only render once both order and products has resolved to avoid accessing properties that have not been resolved yet.

Comment: So my '*ngFor="let product of products; let i = index"' in the option tag is no good?  I thought I need that to iterate over the products (when they are loaded).

Comment: Yes you use ngFor to iterate over the products. But instead of products[i].name try just product.name inside. Avoid accessing the objects via index, just access the object directly.

Comment: Ok, thx.  I'll give that a whirl and also try out your other suggestion regarding getting stuff only after its loaded via ngIf.

Comment: Your problem is so common among developers who have just started learning angular. I recommend you reading [tour-of-heroes-app-and-tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial#tour-of-heroes-app-and-tutorial). You will find the solution of your problem in [Chepter 2](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt2#what-happened) of this tutorial. cheers !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem seems to be here

```
<option *ngFor="let product of products; let i = index" [value]="products[i].id" [selected]="order !== 'undefined' && products[i].id == order.product.id">
```

You are filling your data in two separate asynchronous calls:

```
this.apiService.get("products")
this.apiService.get("orders/"+data.id)
```

So if your products are loaded and they are started to render, but your `order.product` is still `undefined` and you're getting an error when trying to get its id (`order.product.id`).

The quickest solution would be to change it to `order.product?.id` in order to not raise an error before the order was loaded.

Please, let me know if it helps or you need some additional support, information, examples, etc.

Comment: Glad, that I could help. Do you want me to add or concretize something?

Comment: You're good but SO makes me wait 24 hours to let me award the bounty.

Comment: Sure. take your time. Thank you